# c - collecting unknown amount of messages and then continue with the programm

Tags: c, sockets

I want to fetch multiple messages(broadcasts) from a socket but I don't know how many there are and then continue with the program. 
The messages are triggered by a broadcast in the network, so they should appear in a short time window.

I figured I want to loop over `recvfrom()` on the socket I set up earlier and want to use a timeout to know that I got them all. For the timeout I considered `select()` and `setsockopt()` and thought the second would suffice.

The question is now what happens when my `recvfrom()` gets a timeout.
Does it return -1 and sets an `errno`? If yes what would be the `errno`? So I can fetch it and continue.

Or is this better done in another way?

Comment: The documentation is available [online](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html).

Comment: I used the one on die.net and it did not cover ETIMEDOUT for whatever reason. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `O_NONBLOCK` is not set at the socket where message is arriving from.

If no messages are available at the socket and `O_NONBLOCK` is not set on the socket's file descriptor, `recvfrom()` shall block until a message arrives.

If no messages are available at the socket and `O_NONBLOCK` is set on the socket's file descriptor, `recvfrom()` shall fail and set errno to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

**Regarding Return Value**

Upon successful completion, `recvfrom()` shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, `recvfrom()` shall return `0`. Otherwise, the function shall return `-1` and set `errno` to indicate the error.

More details can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html)

Comment: Well I shall use the documentation there the one on die.net was lacking `ETIMEDOUT` for example. I fear that nonblocking may cause a more remote(1000km) client to not be recognized. But then again i can try multiple times with a wait when I use `0=NONBLOCK`. I may try this.

Comment: I think your system or hardware configuration should be capable of handling connectivity issues between client and host there is not much you can do besides setting the timeout value.  Please try and share your observations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the socket in non-blocking mode. From socket(7)

> ```
>    It  is  possible  to  do  nonblocking  I/O  on sockets by setting the O_NONBLOCK flag on a socket file
>    descriptor using fcntl(2).  Then all operations that would block will  (usually)  return  with  EAGAIN
>    (operation should be retried later); connect(2) will return EINPROGRESS error.  The user can then wait
>    for various events via poll(2) or select(2).
> ```

So this way you can get all the data that already arrived with `read`, as stated read will return `-1` and set errno to `EAGAIN` when socket buffer is empty.

This way you will not need to deal with timeouts, but you can still wait explicitly with timeouts.